# Random color in collection instances

Tags: materials, collections, instances, random

I have a collection of cubes with a random color. How can I make the cubes in the collection instances have the same color as in the main collection, and not change randomly?
[image: Text]

Comment: I don't understand the question. If you want to randomize per collection, use different materials for each collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a setup like this:

[image]

Dividing is important because of [this](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/textures/noise.html#notes).

Set different object index here for each cube:

[image]

Comment: +1 You can also quickly set all the objects to have their own pass_index with a short script like [this](https://pastebin.com/bwYsCRui).

Comment: Thank you, that's just what I need.